# esporting data from userform of vba excel to mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

Belwo I have pasted the code i am using to export data entered into the userform1 and userform2 to mysql databas as well as paste it to a particular sheet in excel...my code is running without error and is pating the data into the excel sheet but is not updating my database. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
Private Sub cbStockCategory_Change()
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("UserDetails")
Dim newRow3 As Long
newRow3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws2.Range("A:A"))
ws2.Cells(newRow3, 5).Value = Date
ws2.Cells(newRow3, 6).Value = Time
ws2.Cells(newRow3, 7).Value = Me.cbStockCategory.Value

Dim cntMyConnection As ADODB.Connection
Set cntMyConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Dim entry As String


CnctSource = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;Database=project505;Uid=root;pwd=password;OPTION=3"

cntMyConnection.Open ConnectionString:=CnctSource

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")

entry = "INSERT INTO project505.userdetails (FirstName, Surname, Gender, Email, LoginDate, LoginTime, CategoryChecked) VALUES ('" & UserForm1.txtFirstname.Value & "', '" & UserForm1.txtSurname.Value & "', '" & UserForm1.cbGender.Value & "', '" & UserForm1.txtEmail.Value & "', '" & Date & "', '" & Time & "', '" & Me.cbStockCategory.Value & "')"

Set rs = Nothing
cntMyConnection.Close
Set cntMyConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing quotes for the field values which are apparently strings add something as `'" & UserForm1.txtFirstname.Value & "'`and for others.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i did what you said and then corrected my syntax...but still its not updating....i have updated my code

Comment: I think you are not executing the query. You have query in the string `entry` but where are you executing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siddharth, Check your **INSERT** query It has 7 paramters and at the time of passing parameters you have missed comma between Time and Category Checked.

Your Query:

```
"INSERT INTO project505.userdetails (FirstName, Surname, Gender, Email, LoginDate, LoginTime, CategoryChecked) VALUES (" & UserForm1.txtFirstname.Value & ", " & UserForm1.txtSurname.Value & ", " & UserForm1.cbGender.Value & "," & UserForm1.txtEmail.Value & ", " & Date & "," & Time & Me.cbStockCategory.Value & ")"
```

It should have been like this:

```
"INSERT INTO project505.userdetails (FirstName, Surname, Gender, Email, LoginDate, LoginTime, CategoryChecked) VALUES ('" & UserForm1.txtFirstname.Value & "', '" & UserForm1.txtSurname.Value & "', '" & UserForm1.cbGender.Value & "','" & UserForm1.txtEmail.Value & "', " & Date & "," & Time & ", " & Me.cbStockCategory.Value & ")"
```

**Note:** Based on the data type, add single quote(') around the parameter if its a string.

Comment: Paresh I corrected that but still my data is not getting updated to  my database...what can be the possible reason?

Comment: First, What is the error? Second, check all the datatypes of table 'userdetails' and if its the text use (') around the values in the code. Can you edit the code and paste the lastest code in your question?

Comment: every column in that table is a varchar except for LoginDate which is Date and LoginTime which is Time

Comment: @SiddharthSaurav: Your query seems to be correct. I am not able to see .Execute in your code. Without it, you will not be able to insert data into database then. Use cntMyConnection.Execute (entry) before Set rs = Nothing. Actually there's no need of Set rs = Nothing statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot...that last thing u told did the magic :) thnks a ton :)